# Android: Button.setText() performance

Tags: android

I am developing an Android phone application which has 64 buttons. I will change the text on each button rapidly and continuously. For example the text on one button will be update every 25ms. I change the text on the button by:

```
button.setText(String.format("%d", integer));
```

However when I test the application on some slower phone, the apps lag. And if I remove this part of code, the apps become okay.

Having discussed with my friend, he says each of the .setText method will refresh the screen once. Therefore I am refreshing the screen at rate 25ms / 64 button = 0.4ms. So some slower phone has problem.

I want to ask is it true?
And if it is true, how to solve the problem?

Comment: do your buttons make by programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

in my applications, it has 60 buttons. every 60 seconds, they refresh their contents.

Buttons are inflated by gridview. its contents set by adapter with reuse pattern. it doen't matter.

Answer (score 0):

you change your button's text in main thread,so the apps lag.
you should change button's text in other Thread, don't in Main Thread.

Comment: I reviewed the explanation about the threads in the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html    .It says we should not manipulate the UI components from outside the main/UI thread. Any idea?

Comment: He was referring to the UI thread, but I said is asynchronous thread, not the same